# Python - Maximum number of times element appear in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the following list `my_list = [ ['red', 'yellow', 'green'], ['red', 'yellow', 'green'], ['red', 'green', 'red']]`, I want to find the element which appears at most. I have implemented a brute-force mathod together with a new list and a dictionary to hold the values for each element but the efficiency is not satisfactory. Which would be the best way to implement this search ? I am using Python 3.

Comment: What do you mean by "brute-force"? It's not like there is a magic algorithm out there that can count elements in a list without iterating over it.

Comment: I used 3 for loops. Copied all different elements in a new `list` and then used one `for` loop to keep track of each item in my new list and two more nested `for` loops for the given list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_list = [ ['red', 'yellow', 'green'], ['red', 'yellow', 'green'], ['red', 'green', 'red']]

new_list = [k for v in my_list for k in v]

from collections import Counter

c = Counter(new_list)

print c.most_common(1)
>>> [('red', 4)]
```

Comment: For sake of memory, use a generator instead of `new_list`:  `print(Counter(element for sublist in my_list for element in sublist).most_common(1))`

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the nested list and apply the `max` function:

```
my_list = [ ['red', 'yellow', 'green'], ['red', 'yellow', 'green'], ['red', 'green', 'red']]
new_list = [i for x in my_list for i in x]
max_val = max(new_list, key=lambda x:new_list.count(x))
```

Output:

```
'red'
```

Comment: `new_list` is just a waste of memory. You can just keep a dictionary in memory and count as you go.

Comment: @DeepSpace your solution would be more efficient, but how exactly would that save space?

Comment: waste of a `lambda` here

Comment: @Ajax1234 `new_list` is a waste of memory since it is an unnecessary flattened version of `my_list`. It can be turned into a generator at least.

Comment: `from collections import Counter ; print(Counter(element for sublist in my_list for element in sublist).most_common(1))  ;  #  [('red', 4)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten your list with `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, then use a `collections.defaultdict` to store the counts, and getting the max key is easy from there:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import chain

my_list = [['red', 'yellow', 'green'], ['red', 'yellow', 'green'], ['red', 'green', 'red']]

d = defaultdict(int)
for word in chain.from_iterable(my_list):
    d[word] += 1

print(max(d.items(), key = itemgetter(1))[0])
# red
```